# Laravel Listener Priorities

Tags: php, events, laravel

Let's say I have two listeners in Laravel like so:

```
Event::listen('eventOne', 'myListenerOne');
Event::listen('eventThree', 'myListenerThree');
```

I know by default the listener priority is set to 0. But what if I want to add an event between the two above?

```
Event::listen('eventTwo', 'myListenerTwo');
```

What would I set the priority to?

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel <= 5.3**

Just add your listener with greater priority, say 1

```
Event::listen('eventTwo', 'myListenerTwo', 1);
```

Here is a small example to better understand event priorities

```
Event::listen(
     'test', function () {
             echo 'On test, first added but last executed', PHP_EOL;
         }, -1);


Event::listen(
     'test', function () {
             echo 'On test, added in the middle and executed in the middle', PHP_EOL;
         });


Event::listen(
     'test', function () {
             echo 'On test, last added but first executed', PHP_EOL;
         }, 1);

Event::fire('test');
```

*P.S.:*

*You can always check yourself by looking into laravel sources, for example into [Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::sortListeners](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php#L300).*

*P.P.S.:*

Event priorities [has been removed in Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade)